# Using the value of a variable as another variables name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, dynamic-variables

I'm just starting out in learning Ruby and I've written a program that generates some numbers and assigns them to variables @one, @two, @three etc. The user can then specify a variable to change by inputting it's name (e.g one). I then need to do something like '@[valueofinout] = asd'. How would I do this, and is there a better way as the way I'm thinking of seems to be discouraged? I've found

```
x = "myvar"
myvar = "hi"
eval(x) -> "hi"
```

but I don't completely understand why the second line is needed. In my case would I use something like

```
@one = "21"
input = "one"
input = "@" + input
changeto = "22"
eval(input) -> changeto
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `instance_variable_set` ([rubydoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000368))

```
instance_variable_set("@" + varname, value)
```

In most cases though, you should separate your normal Ruby variables from the variables your user is interacting with. How about creating a Hash of user variables, e.g.

```
@uservars = { 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2 }
two = @uservars['two']   # Look up 'two' variable

varname = "myvar"
@uservars[varname] = 5   # Set a variable by name
value = @uservars[varname]  # Get a variable by name
```

Comment: wow, this is actually one area where PHP outshines ruby in terms of cleanliness of syntax.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4169891/2951835

Comment: Ruby makes it hard to do because it's ugly, you're rarely need to set a user specified variable of an instance unless you are metaprogramming. Dynamically messing with global variables is a security hole; if you want a set of user-defined variables then you probably want a hash.

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables can be retrieved via this method:

```
input = instance_variable_get("@one")
```

After this, in your case you'll have `input` equal to "21".

Comment: Hi, I'm not quite whether that would work for what I need. I'd need to have something that would assign a certain number to a variable (say variable A) but the name of variable A is not known. The name of variable A is stored within variable B though so I'd need to use the value of variable B to assign something to variable A. AFAICT this can't be done with instance_variable_get.

Comment: @hrickards: Do you know the possibles values of A ? if you do there is an other way. But the intance_variable_get should do what you want !

Comment: @Niklaos An integer between and including 1 and 49

Comment: There are only six possible names for variable A, so it would be possible to use if else statements to check for all of them, but I thought there'd be a cleaner way. Is there not?