# what is "$$" in PHP

Tags: php, variable-variables

I saw this code

```
if (is_null($$textVarName)) {
$$textVarName = $_defaultTexts[$type];
}
```

what is code "$$" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does $$ mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does $$ (dollar dollar or double dollar) mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-dollar-dollar-or-double-dollar-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's evil is what it is.

That will take the value that's in `$textVarName` and use that as a variable name. For example:

```
$foo = 'hello';
$hello = 'The Output';
echo $$foo; // displays "The Output"
```

Comment: @VoteyDisciple; is that endless? Can I have `$$$foo`? Or it stops at two?

Comment: @Beemer: it is endless. Btw, it is faster to try - than ask and wait for answer.

Comment: @zerkms: thanks for the answer, but did it occur to you that I might not have a compiler handy?

Comment: @zerkms: Cool link, which is exactly why I asked my question.  I wouldn't have known about this link if I didn't ask that question.  I ask to get more than what I just asked.  Thanks!

Comment: i can see how it would be confusing and thus "evil", but this is so elegant. It's quite a useful feature at times, which requires messy syntax in other languages to accomplish. It's not too different from dereferencing pointers in C++. If that's fine, then so should this. If this is evil, then so would multiple pointer dereferences in C++

Comment: Multiple pointer dereferences in C++ are pretty evil too (hence all the post-C++ languages that no longer include explicit declared pointers), but at least they're expected. What makes this particularly wicked in PHP is that it's exceptionally unusual, and any quick reading of the source is likely to overlook a rogue `$$` in there. I have never encountered a situation where a variable variable was a better choice than a hash map or other data structure.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)$$key=$value;
```

now, automagically, if the previous form had a field named 'username' you now have a variable called $username that holds the value submitted in the form.
not the greatest or secure method, but when you have a pocket full of nails, this is a heck of a hammer

this is pretty bad practice and is never encouraged but all PHP coders I know  secretly sorta like it.

Comment: Hi, I'm cfreak and I'm a PHP coder. Now you know me. I absolutely hate it. :-) (of course I don't really like PHP at all but it pays the bills so I do it)

Comment: Despite it being bad practice... I love it!!  I once had like 50 entries in the `$_POST` and it was definitely not fun to make a variable for each (even with automating that with something like Excel). Wish I knew this shortcut back then.

Comment: Note that you can use `extract($_POST,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,"p_")` to achieve the same effect - plus more security with a variable prefix. Bonus points for `array_map` filtering.

Comment: Plus, what's wrong with just writing `$_POST['foo']`? I've ***never*** felt compelled to extract (manually or otherwise) a variable from `$_POST` unless I had a specific reason to do additional processing with that one variable.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php