# PHP variable not working when referenced with '$'

Tags: php, variable-variables

I'm trying to convert a PHP variable to a JS variable using a little helper function that uses [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). To simplify, here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
 $project_key = 'project 1';

 function to_js($variable) {
     echo $$variable;
 }

 to_js('$project_key');
```

this is supposed simply print

```
project 1
```

instead i get

```
Undefined variable: $project_key
```

which tells me the variable is being targeted but can't be accessed from the function. How can I access the global var `$project_key` from within the function if supplied only with the string `$project_key`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omit the leading $ from `$project_key` in the following line:

```
to_js('$project_key');
```

It should be:

```
to_js('project_key');
```

The `$` in a variable is not part of the variables name, so you don't need to include it when referencing it in a variable variable.

Answer (score 1):

Remove first `$` sign before `$variable`. If you use [**`$$`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php) the `project 1` will be considered as a variable but that is not defined as a variable.

```
$project_key = 'project 1';

function to_js($variable) {
    echo $variable;
}

to_js($project_key);
```

[**Reference of `$$`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: let's define it. `global $$variable;` no error, no output :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes in:

> `to_js('$project_key');`

To be `to_js($project_key);` as if you use it as `to_js('$project_key');` then you set the `$variable` in the function to the text: `'$project_key'`.

**Wrong answer!

@mehedi-pstu2k9 answer's is correct**

> [**Reference of $$**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

**See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169891/4977144**

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing your variable with script tags around it.

```
echo "<script>var x =" . $variable . "</script>";
```

`$variable` - being the variable you have stored in php
x - being the variable you want to be stored in Javascript.