# How to Insert The Values

Tags: php, html

I have a variable like:

```
foreach ($array as $data){
    $namee=$data['Label_Field'];
    ${$namee} = $_POST[$namee];
}
```

How do I get a value like ("data", "data") using those variables?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. What is `("data", "data")` supposed to be? An array?

Comment: Maybe this? `$$namee = $_POST[$namee];`

Comment: Here I Have A Dynamic Form And I Have To insert the data into the database  that's why I need a dynamic varriable

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$$` in php

**Example:**

```
$a = 'name';
$$a = 'test';
echo $name;
```

Result:

```
test
```

**Example of your code:**

```
foreach ($array as $data){
    $namee = $data['Label_Field'];
    $$namee = $_POST[$namee];
}
```

I also suggest you read the following:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-vs-operator/

https://www.javatpoint.com/php-dollar-doubledollar

[what is "$$" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169882/what-is-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using variable variables, simply filter $_POST into a new variable, else there is a likely risk of overwriting important variables ($db_connection?).

Instead do some thing like:

```
<?php
$_POST['foo'] = '';
$_POST['bar'] = '';
$_POST['baz'] = '';

// fields
$fields = [['Label_Field' => 'foo']];

// just labels
$labels = array_column($fields, 'Label_Field');

// filter $_POST by keys which are in $labels
$data = array_filter($_POST, fn($k) => in_array($k, $labels), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

print_r($data);
```

Then use `$data['foo']` instead of `$foo`.

View online: https://3v4l.org/vna02