# Convert string to variable name in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have variables

```
 <% mon_has_two_sets_of_working_hours = 0 %>
 <% tue_has_two_sets_of_working_hours = 0 %>
 <% wed_has_two_sets_of_working_hours = 0 %>
```

I want to change the values of these variables dynamically.

```
 <% days_array = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed'] %>

 <% days_array.each do |day| %>
   <% if condition? %>
    # here i want to set %>
     <% "#{day}__has_two_sets_of_working_hours" = 1 %>
  end
 end
```

The value is not getting assigned. Is there any way to assign value to variable dynamically?

Comment: Do, do, do use arrays (or hashes) for that.

Comment: The answer to [2530112](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530112) should help, it recommends `instance_variable_set`.

Comment: Dynamically creating a variable name on the fly is doable in some languages, including Ruby, but has been falling out of favor for years, and is considered a curiosity mostly. It leads to confusion which leads to maintenance problems, so sidestep the problem and use a hash. It can also lead to security problems if the variable names are coming from user-supplied input, or could cause weird bugs if a name collided with a previously created variable.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do this. There is with instance or class variables, but with local variables there is very rarely a good need.

In your case you really should have the data in a hash. Also, logic like this really does not belong in erb. You want something like:

```
working_hour_sets = %w[mon tue wed thu fri sat sun].inject({}) do |hash, day|
  hash[day]=0;
  hash
end
# puts working_hour_sets #=> {"wed"=>0, "sun"=>0, "thu"=>0, "mon"=>0, "tue"=>0, "sat"=>0, "fri"=>0}

working_hour_sets.each do |day, value|
  working_hour_sets[day] = 1 if condition?
end
```

Comment: It is doable using eval, but you are right saying that it should not be done that way. Using a hash instead is a better solution.

Comment: Or you could pass this block to `inject`: `{|hash,day|hash.merge(day=>0)}`

Answer (score 2):

Now, I know this question is a bit old, but there is an easier way to do this and is using the standard Ruby `send` method. This is actually one of the methods that make Ruby so agile in the metaprogramming world.

This is actually a config setting I use in a Rails app:

```
# In a YAML    
twitter:
  consumer_key: 'CONSUMER-KEY'
  consumer_secret: 'CONSUMER-SECRET'
  oauth_token: 'OAUTH-KEY'
  oauth_token_secret: 'OAUTH-SECRET'

...

# And in your file.rb
config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "social_keys.yml"))[Rails.env]['twitter']

Twitter.configure do |twitter|
  config.each_key do |k|
    twitter.send("#{k}=", config[k])
  end
end
```

It's DRY and very easy to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer to this old question.

In my scenario, I wanted to count how many times a day showed up in an array of days (`day_array`). I didn't need to know if a day didn't show up in `day_array`, so I didn't initialize the `days_count` hash as [gunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544556/gunn) did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4633870/1359650).

Here's how I did it:

```
def count_days(day_array)
  days_count = {}
  day_array.each do |day|
    days_count[day].nil? ? days_count[day] = 1 : days_count[day] = days_count[day] + 1
  end
  puts days_count
end
```

If I copy and paste the above in irb, then:

```
> count_days(%w[SU MO])
{"SU"=>1, "MO"=>1}

> count_days(%w[SU SU MO])
{"SU"=>2, "MO"=>1}
```

Basically, consistent with prior answers. But, I thought an additional example couldn't hurt.