# Can I call the value of a variable as another variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, variables

I have 3 environments to work with, and need to choose a value based on which environment I'm in. I have a dynamic variable `$environment` that could be either development, test, or production. I want to also have other variables:

```
$development
$test
$production
```

that have values to be used based on which environment I'm working in.

Is there some way of calling $($environment) and using the result of the environment variable as another variable? To clarify:

$abc = "prod"
$prod = "production-value"

I want to call something like $($abc) and have that return "production-value"

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530112/using-the-value-of-a-variable-as-another-variables-name-in-ruby) but for Ruby; is there a way to do this in Powershell?

Comment: Are you wanting to create a variable name based on the value of another varible? So, $abc = "xyz" and you want to create a variable name of $xyz?

Comment: I want to call a variable of $xyz, it already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `Get-Variable`:

```
$environment = 'test'

$test = 'test'
$prod = 'prod'

(Get-Variable -Name $environment).value
```

Would return the value of the $test variable.

Comment: Beware that whenever you feel the need to actually do this there's a greater than average chance that you should consider using a different data structure instead (e.g. an array or a hashtable).